# How do you specify a certain directory with PickPhotoAsync?

Tags: xamarin

How do you specify a certain directory or path when using `PickPhotoAsync`?

Comment: I don't believe that you can.  It's intended to work with the default photo gallery, not arbitrary folders

Comment: I can set the directory when taking photos using the Directory option with StoreCameraMediaOptions and TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions), but it's invalid with the PickMediaOptions when using PickPhotoAsync.

Comment: Probably a permission thing. Also I don't think it's clear which API you're referring to. Is it this https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin?

Comment: Yes, you can specify where to save new photos from the camera.  But AFAIK it will only display photos from the default gallery.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you specify a certain directory or path when using PickPhotoAsync?

**Unfortunately, it can not.** However, image.path can be getted if be helpful.

From [officila document](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#photos),`Task<MediaFile> PickPhotoAsync(PickMediaOptions options = null);` can not add options with **Directory** .

[image]

However when you taking photo, you can set options with **Directory**:

```
 var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
 {
        Directory = "Sample",
        Name = "test.jpg"
  });
```

Although can not *PickPhotoAsync* from *Directory*,but you can use `file.path` where you want.

```
Image imgTemplateImages = new Image();
if (imgTemplateImages != null)
{
    lblImagePath.Text = "ImagePath" + file.Path;
    byte[] testByte = CommonFunctions.ReadStream(file.GetStream());
    imgTemplateImages.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        file.Dispose();
        return stream;
    });
}
```

Or you can save path to database or webserver to be used next time.

Comment: I'll try file.path again.  I was seeing 2 different paths after taking a photo though.

Comment: @Marie You can show different paths,I will check it. If be helpful , thanks for marking it.^.^